# How to use javascript for a mousedown event to hide a div?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the code below to hide a div using a mousedown event, but it's not working.

I have tried a lot of changes to this code without any luck.

This is my code below:

```
function simulateMouseDown(theelement){
   var eventName = 'mousedown';
   if(theelement.dispatchEvent){
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseClick");
    event.initMouseEvent(eventName, true, true, window);
    alert(theelement.dispatchEvent(event));

   }else if(theelement.fireEvent){ // IE7 and below
     theelement.fireEvent('on'+eventName);
     alert(theelement.dispatchEvent(event));
   }
};
```

Any ideas as to the proper way to do this?

Comment: What isn't working?
Is it a certain event?
Is it the functionality?

Comment: This code does nothing to hide a div. Also you should be more specific about what is not working...

Comment: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

Comment: I have a div with id test and inside this div i have an iframe with class myiframe.

I want to hide the div when someone clicks onto iframe.. Is it possible?

only with javascript no jQuery

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, why did you put it in the tags?

Comment: You know you're programatically creating an event, and not listening for a mouse event, right ?

Comment: And, is the iframe showing a page from your site, or an external site ?

Comment: iframe is showing a page from my site..

Comment: Please post relevant information in the question rather than in the comments so that other people can understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var div    = document.getElementById('test'),
    iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('myiframe')[0];

iframe.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdkfk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){
    document.getElementById('elementToHide').style.display='none';
}, true);
```

Comment: started to write before the tag was removed and before the comment appeared, so I assumed that jQuery was an option, I updated my answer